# Как слить два фрейма данных с разным кол-вом строк?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть два файла. Хочу слить их но если делать через:

```
df = df.merge(df1)
```

то будет следущее. В одном файле `df` время от 10 до 24 часов полностью заполнено в секундах. А во втором `df1` многих "Времен" нету и при сливании таким образом произойдет убирание строк из `df`.

[Пример данных](https://dropmefiles.com/h7oMe).

Это строки из `df`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а эти из `df1`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, во во втором `df1` нету некоторых строк с временем и значения пропущены. Нужно получить, чтобы было так (пропуски стали просто строками с "0"):

```
Date        Time    Value    Id

6/02/2020   100046  0       0
6/02/2020   100047  0       0
6/02/2020   100048  40.280  3202079
6/02/2020   100049  40.270  3202072
6/02/2020   100050  0       0
6/02/2020   100051  0       0
6/02/2020   100052  0       0
6/02/2020   100053  0       0
6/02/2020   100054  40.225  3202071
6/02/2020   100055  0       0
6/02/2020   100056  40.225  3202029
```

Comment: Перед тем как объединять фреймы необходимо пробразовать столбцы, по которым будет происходить объединение к единому типу и формату. В ответе на ваш предыдущий вопрос я показал как это делается. Можете выложить данные, готовые к объединению или привести в вопросе код для чтения и соответствующего преобразования?

Comment: 1.csv - даты и время представлены числами, а в `sec.csv` -  строками да и дата еще в другом формате. Хотите проверить - скачайте файл по ссылке  из вопроса и проверьте содержимое...

Comment: а если бы не работал??? Если нет воспроизводимого примера данных - отвечающие на вопрос не могут проверить собственный ответ и после этого часто возникают бесконечная и ненужная переписка в комментариях

Comment: _хорошо я понял_, пока не заметно, что вы поняли Данные с файлообменника уже удалены, в вопросе картинки вместо текста. Извиниете, но я ставлю заслуженный минус вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь параметром `DataFrame.merge(..., how="left")`:

```
res = df.merge(df1, how="left").fillna(0)
```