# Как заменить нули в фрейме данных на значение до них?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как заменить нули на первое значение перед ними?

То есть, перед нулями в столбце есть последнее значение, нули ниже надо заменить на него.

Вход:

```
6/2/2020    100038  40.29
6/2/2020    100039  40.29
6/2/2020    100040  0
6/2/2020    100041  0
6/2/2020    100042  0
6/2/2020    100043  40.25
6/2/2020    100044  0
6/2/2020    100045  0
6/2/2020    100046  0
6/2/2020    100047  0
6/2/2020    100048  40.28
6/2/2020    100049  40.27
6/2/2020    100050  0
6/2/2020    100051  0
```

Выход:

```
6/2/2020    100038  40.29
6/2/2020    100039  40.29
6/2/2020    100040  40.29
6/2/2020    100041  40.29
6/2/2020    100042  40.29
6/2/2020    100043  40.25
6/2/2020    100044  40.25
6/2/2020    100045  40.25
6/2/2020    100046  40.25
6/2/2020    100047  40.25
6/2/2020    100048  40.28
6/2/2020    100049  40.27
6/2/2020    100050  40.27
6/2/2020    100051  40.27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подозреваю, что этот вопрос связан с [вашим предыдущим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1217768). В этом случае можно сделать так:

```
res = df.merge(df1, how="left").ffill()
```

Answer (score 1):

Тривиальный цикл не подходит?

```
import pandas as pd
ds=pd.Series([40.29,40.29,0,0,0,40.25,0,0,0,40.28,40.27,0,0])
for i,elt in enumerate(ds):
    if elt!=0:
        curr=elt
    else:
        ds[i]=curr

0     40.29
1     40.29
2     40.29
3     40.29
4     40.29
5     40.25
6     40.25
7     40.25
8     40.25
9     40.28
10    40.27
11    40.27
12    40.27
```

Поскольку вы не привели законченный минимальный пример -  от Series перейти к DataFrame надеюсь сумеете самостоятельно.